# Column calculated by column with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table -

```
id | date | type | value
-------------------------
1   1/1/14   A      1
2   1/1/14   A      10
3   2/1/14   A      10
4   2/1/14   A      15
5   2/1/14   B      15
6   2/1/14   B      20
```

I would like to create a new column which calculates the minimum value per day per type. So giving the following results -

```
id | date | type | value | min_day
-----------------------------------
1   1/1/14   A      1        1
2   1/1/14   A      10       1
3   2/1/14   A      10       10
4   2/1/14   A      15       10 
5   2/1/14   B      15       15
6   2/1/14   B      20       15
```

Is this possible? If so how would I go about it? I've been looking into triggers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a field named `min_day` in your table. Then you can use `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` query.

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableName T1  JOIN
   (SELECT date,type,MIN(value) as MinValue
   FROM TableName
   GROUP BY type,date) T2 ON T1.type=T2.type AND T1.date=T2.date
SET T1.min_day = T2.MinValue
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32855/9).

**EDIT:**

For day-wise grouping:

```
UPDATE TableName T1 JOIN
  (SELECT MONTH(date) as mon,type,MIN(value) as MinValue
  FROM TableName
  GROUP BY type,MONTH(date)) T2 ON T1.type=T2.type AND MONTH(T1.date)=T2.mon
SET T1.min_day = T2.MinValue
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c1e/27).

Comment: That's great! How do include times but still min by day? So using the data   (1, '2014-01-01 10:00:00', 'A', 1),(2, '2014-01-01 01:00:00', 'A', 10),

Comment: @NorthSide: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Yes, sorry, instead of there just being a date such as 2014-01-01 the would be a date and time. So within the Fiddle you sent the times may be different throughout the day, when I try this currently its not working - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c1e/1/0

Comment: @NorthSide: See the edit in my answer. It will get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Do I need to do the update and set part as in your first solution? Though the fiddle is working great if I run your second solution to my actual test table it isn't working correctly, it's always coming back with MinValue as 0. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: @NorthSide: I think the second query would be much better. Why it returns 0? Does value field contains 0 for all days? I think that is the reason.

Comment: I'm just checking through my data now. How do I add this min value to the column as in your first example?

Comment: @NorthSide: The first example will update the table itself with the mindate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table's name is mytable, try this:

```
SELECT mt.id,
  mt.date,
  mt.type,
  mt.value,
  mt.min_day,
  md.min_value
FROM mytable mt
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT date, MIN(value) min_value FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE
  ) md
ON mt.date=md.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.min_day
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN
  (SELECT date,TYPE,
               min(value) AS min_day
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY date,TYPE) AS t2 ON t1.TYPE = t2.TYPE
AND t1.date = t2.date
```